# Add property runtime in Objective c

Tags: ios7

How to add property in runtime and sampleItem is my item class and I am presenting the .h and .m file. It has two properties but I want add one more property in run time.

```
sampleItem.h  
@interface sampleItem : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic)  NSString *city;

- (id) initToDefaults;
@end


sampleItem.m
- (id) initToDefaults
{
self. name = @"";
self.city = @" ";
}
```

Am using above item class with two properties in my project. This is a class using in my project as a entity. Now my question is want to add one more property in runtime.

Can any body please solve my problem.

Comment: [Does using Google hurt?](https://www.google.hu/search?q=objective-c+add+property+at+run+time) I mean, the **first two** hits are both Stack Overflow answers to this very problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can add more properties in runtime or on the fly **but** with some **limitations**.

But as an alternative  you can use `NSMutableDictionary` as a store and keep any number of objects on the fly as an example here.

```
// sampleItem.h  

@interface sampleItem : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *store;

@end
```

and save like:

```
[store setObject:@"Your name" forKey@"nameKey"];
[store setObject:@"Your city" forKey@"cityKey"];
```

retrive like:

```
NSString *name = [store objectForKey:@"nameKey"];
NSString *city = [store objectForKey:@"cityKey"];
```

but make sure to initiate the store like:

```
_store = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

before you use.